# requestsで画像urlの画像を送りたい

Tags: python, python3, python-requests

`file = {'file': ('report.jpg',  requests.get(image_url).content)}`

みたいな感じで、urlの画像を送信する方法ってあるんでしょうか？
一回一回この画像を保存してやらないといけないんでしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import requests

image_url = 'https://example.com/image.jpg'

response = requests.post('https://example.com/upload', files={'file': (image_url, requests.get(image_url).content)})

print(response.text)
```

('file', (image_url, requests.get(image_url).content))のタプルをfilesに渡しています。これで一時的な保存なしに画像を直接送信できると思うので試してみて下さい。

もう少し詳しい情報があれば修正します。